# Как добавить в БД несколько записей при помощи PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Формирую вот такой запрос.

```
 INSERT INTO `tasks_users` (`task_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (55, 1),(55, 2),(55, 3),(55, 4),(55, 5),(55, 6),(55, 7),(55, 8),(55, 9);
```

Как мне его отправить одним запросом?

Я смог отправить только циклом, но это наверное не правильно:

```
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `tasks_users` (`task_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (:task_id, :user_id)');

$query->execute([':task_id'=>$taskId, ':user_id'=>$userId]);
```

Comment: Это абсолютно правильно и нормально. Разве только стоит [завернуть цикл в транзакцию](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert#multiple)

Comment: Если вам нужна гарантия, чтобы все запросы вставки выполнялись точно, можно оформить их внутри транзакции.

Comment: Если у вас один запрос, то в чем проблема его выполнить? Или у вас проблема сформировать такой запрос?

Comment: Да проблема сформировать.

Comment: 1) Уточните версию MySQL; 2) Требуется вставка именно такого набора данных - совпадающее значение `task_id` и последовательные значения `user_id` в заданном диапазоне (или не последовательные, списком)?

Comment: MySQL 5.7. `INSERT INTO `tasks_users` (`task_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (55, 1),(55, 2),(55, 3),(55, 4),(55, 5),(55, 6),(55, 7),(55, 8),(55, 9);` Этот запрос я формирую сам циклом и эти значения могут быть всегда разными . Когда я использовал  `mysqli_query` я просто отправлял запрос а с PDO так не проходит.

Comment: с PDO "так" прекрасно проходит. если следовать общему принципу - каждая переменная в запросе заменяется на плейсхолдер, и потом передается в execute. Другое дело что нет смысла так извращаться - запрос в цикле ничуть не хуже.

Comment: На производительность базы это не повлияет?

Comment: в лог запишется N запросов вместо одного. в любом случае на большом объеме данных множественная вставка будет гораздо эффективнее чем отдельные запросы.

Comment: @teran define "гораздо".

Comment: @Ипатьев я думаю вы в состоянии и сами загуглить? [тут](https://medium.com/@benmorel/high-speed-inserts-with-mysql-9d3dcd76f723) например пишут про 6-17 раз по скорости в завсимости от того, локальный сервер или нет. И [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793209/1216425) вдогонку

Comment: @teran на сарае тоже кое-какое слово пишут. А внутри лежит совсем другое. Не нужно верить всему, что пишут в интернете.

Comment: @Ипатьев _"If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time, use INSERT statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert several rows at a time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some cases) than using separate single-row INSERT statements."_ [достаточно хороший сарай](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html)?

Comment: @teran это официальный сарай, но конкретики там нет. А практика показывает что разница незначительная. А все кто получают 17 раз рразницы, *разумеется* измеряют только кривизну своих рук и ничего больше.

Comment: @Ипатьев ога, так и написать там в комментариях "Ипатьев говорит, что шляпа все у вас тут, ему виднее". Нет смысла спорить с оф. доками, если пишут, что в некоторых случаях может достигаться значительный прирост, значит так и есть. Если у вас прирост таковой не наблюдался, значит это были не те случаи, или тоже руки не достаточно прямые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот то, что мне подошло.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tasks_users` (`task_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (55, 1),(55, 2),(55, 3),(55, 4),(55, 5),(55, 6),(55, 7),(55, 8),(55, 9)";
```

`$pdo->exec($sql);`

Если БД находится на другом сервере, то это более быстрый вариант.